# Appending local MySQL data to same MySQL data in web server

Tags: database

my IT boss wanted this scenario to be undertaken: First, we develop an Alumni program using PHP and deploy this in the web server which can be accessed by that school alumni in the web to update their personal data anytime. Then, using exactly that SAME program we must also deploy this locally, thru the LAN in its satellite campus which is far and have a very erratic and unreliable internet connection. The purpose is that that the latter system (in LAN) can still be used to add new alumni data even during "offline" periods, and then, once the internet signal is OK, or now being "online" to just upload these offline-generated data in MySQL to the web server hosting THE SAME software program. How do we do a seamless data transfer then of this MySQL database - from the LAN to the web server - once the online signal is now steady?
Thanks for any advice...

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?

Answer (score 0):

A good start might be to look at MySQL replication.

> Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master)
>   to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves).
>   Replication is asynchronous - slaves need not be connected permanently
>   to receive updates from the master. This means that updates can occur
>   over long-distance connections and even over temporary or intermittent
>   connections such as a dial-up service. Depending on the configuration,
>   you can replicate all databases, selected databases, or even selected
>   tables within a database.

For more info, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Hi Reaan, please advice further: will this process overwrite the MySQL data in the master-server or will it only ADD the new records in the master-server as inputted from the slave server?

Comment: Doesn't the question indicate that "synchronous" replication is required since the internet site needs to be completely replaced by the LAN site when not unavailable? According to your link, MySQL only does this with their Cluster.